# Comparar campo nulo

Tags: oracle, ireport

Boa tarde gente, tudo bem?
Estou montando um relatório no financeiro onde desejo criar uma campo que me retorne se esse valor foi pago ou não. A query verifica a data da baixa se a mesma for preenchida ele irá mostrar no campo que o valor foi pago e se tiver vazio vai mostrar que não foi pago. Porém estou com dificuldades nessa comparação. Poderiam me mostrar o erro na query:
`SELECT NUFIN,AD_DTVENCALTER,DHBAIXA
CASE DHBAIXA 
WHEN dhbaixa IS NULL THEN 'Não'
WHEN dhbaixa  NOT NULL THEN 'sim' 
END AS situação
FROM TGFFIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que apenas falte uma vírgula antes de `CASE` e também não tenho certeza, mas no caso de checar como `NULL` nem precisa colocar no `CASE` o nome da coluna, você já adicionou no `WHEN` (por cause do `IS NULL`)

E algo que nem chega a ser um problema mas facilitaria seria usar o `ELSE` ao invés de outro `WHEN` quando a condição é "contraria" a outra

Deve ser isto o que deseja (me comunique se algo falhar, não pude testar):

```
SELECT NUFIN, AD_DTVENCALTER, DHBAIXA,
  CASE
      WHEN dhbaixa IS NULL THEN 'Não'
      ELSE 'sim' 
   END AS situação
FROM TGFFIN
```

Eu não tenho certeza porque raramente usei acentos em nomes, mas se falhar para o `AS situação` troque-o por:

```
END AS "situação"
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, amigo. Deu certinho.
Estou começando agora nessa caminhada e to sofrendo haha

Comment: @PabloDosSantosNeves por favor marque a resposta como correta, ja que resolveu o seu problema. Grato!

Comment: Prontinho @guilhermeNascimento. Perdão, estou aprendendo a usar o fórum ainda. Não tenho experiencia com esse tipo de comunidade.

Comment: Sem problemas, obrigado!